# How do I access an SD card via command line in Chrome OS?

Tags: block-device, chrome-os

I'm trying to use the command line in terminal to unzip a massive .zip archive on my SD card. My understanding is that normally, I would locate the SD card in `/dev/`, mount the card, and then I should have read/write privileges.

But I don't know the name of the correct device node. `diskutil list` is not available AFAIK.  What should I do?

I am running ChromeOS Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit), and using the Terminal via Crostini

Comment: Provide the error info you met

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm not sure what you mean by error info. If you mean what happens if I try to run `diskutil list`, the message I receive is `-bash: diskutil: command not found`

Comment: Mount it then access it.

Comment: My understanding is that in order to mount the SD card, I need the name of the SD card in the filesystem. However, I am unable to find the name of the SD card

Comment: try `lsblk`, it should output all your block devices. Even it doesn't work, you should be able to plug it off to see which device mode disappeared or plug it in to see which device just appeared.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried running `lsblk` both with and without the SD card. For both, I get the same output:

`NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT`
`vda  254:0    0 244.5M  1 disk /opt/google/cros-containers`
`vdb  254:16   0  15.5G  0 disk /dev/wl0`

Comment: You might also give `fdisk -l` a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out accessing external storage via command line is not available in Version 70.0 of ChromeOS, and support is still pending to arrive in Version 72. At least according to [this news article](https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/chrome-os-72-dev-channel-usb-sd-card-support-project-crostini-chromebooks-android-9-pie/).  For now, I will have to unzip the archive in a different machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am running ChromeOS Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit).

1. Check Settings > Developers > Manage shared folders...

- If your SD Card is not listed, you need to enable it for Linux:
- Use the "Files" utility (if not pinned on Shelf, from "Launcher"  search for "Files" and open the utility). On the "Files" window you can probably see "My files", "Google Drive", and "SD Card"...
- Right-click on "SD Card" >  "Share with Linux"

2. On Settings > Developers > Manage shared folders...your card should be listed.
3. Now use your terminal...

   [user]@penguin:~$ cd "/mnt/chromeos/removable/SD Card"
   [user]@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/removable/SD Card$

Answer (score 0):

1. Open crosh
2. load `shell`
3. `cd "/media/removable/SD Card/"`
4. `ls` etc.

If `unzip` doesn't work by default you can install it with [chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew)